# Error: Invalid IL code in SDK.Service:.ctor (): IL_001d: pop

Tags: c#, node.js, mono, edgejs

I'm working with edge-js in my nodejs project. I added dll file and import it like this:

```
getHID = edge.func({
    source: function() {/*
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using SDK.DataModel;
    using SDK;
    public class Startup
    {
        public async Task<object> Invoke(dynamic input)
        {
            string personId = input.nationalCode;

            DO_IDENTIFIER healthCareProvider = new DO_IDENTIFIER();
            healthCareProvider.Issuer = input.dedicated_organization;
            healthCareProvider.Assigner = input.exporter_organization;
            healthCareProvider.Type = input.type;
            healthCareProvider.ID = input.medicalNumber;
           
            DO_CODED_TEXT insurer = new DO_CODED_TEXT();
            insurer.Value = input.name;
            insurer.Terminology_id = input.code;
            string codedString = (input.id).ToString();
            insurer.Coded_string = codedString;

            Service srv = new Service();

            var result = srv.GetHIDurgent(personId, healthCareProvider, insurer, null);

            return result;
        }
    }
 */},
    references: ['OIS_TestMode_2_KeyA3.dll']
})
```

When I remove `Service srv = new Service()` and `result` it work perfectly with no error.
But when I add `Service srv = new Service()` and `result` it complied but throw me this error:
`Error: Invalid IL code in SDK.Service:.ctor (): IL_001d: pop`

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should have a usb token
it has a windows installer
install that and keep usp connected.
then it should work.